# PHP eval() is this exploitable in my code? (dynamic arguments)

Tags: php, mysqli, eval, prepared-statement

**EDIT:** after reading all the input from the other users, i decided, to use what @chris suggested **call_user_func_array()** one more reason not to use **eval()** its slower than **call_user_func_array()**, but so far, nobody was able to exploit it my way, if you find a way, please post it as answer or comment :). So everybody can learn from it.
Merry XMAS to all!

**---EDIT END---**

Ok i needed to make a dynamic code:

I get user input like **$_POST['a'], $_POST['b'];** // Depends on each query how many user input.

```
$sql = "SELECT 1, 2, 3 FROM x WHERE b = ? AND a = ? LIMIT 10"; // SQL STATEMENT
$input = array($_POST['a'], $_POST['b']);
$output = 3; // Number of variables need for 1, 2, 3
$data = readDB2($sql, $input, $output);
var_dump($data);
```

this input, gets passed to mysqli->prepared statements

cause the number of variables is dynamic ($input and $output);

i used the php function eval(); Now my question can this be exploited, in my code?

Just look in my function readDB2 to see how i used the eval() function (used it 3x times).

```
public function readDB2($sql, $input, $output1) {

    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql);
    if(!empty($input) && is_array($input)) {
        $sp = "";
        $data = "";
        $inputn = count($input) - 1;
        for($i = 0; $i <= $inputn; $i++) {
            if($i !== $inputn) {
                $data .= '$input[' . $i . "],";
            } else {
                $data .= '$input[' . $i . "]";
            }
            $sp .= "s";
        }
        $bind = '$stmt->bind_param(\''. $sp . '\',' . $data . ');';
        eval("return $bind");
    }
    if (!$stmt) {throw new Exception($this->mysqli->error);}
    $stmt->execute();
    if (!$stmt) {throw new Exception($this->mysqli->error);}
    $stmt->store_result();
    $checker = $stmt->num_rows;
    if($checker !== 0) {
        if(!empty($output1)) {
            $out = "";
            for($i = 1; $i <= $output1; $i++) {
                if($i !== $output1) {
                    $out .= '$out' . $i . ",";
                } else {
                    $out .= '$out' . $i;
                }
            }
            $res = '$stmt->bind_result(' . $out . ');';
            eval("return $res");

            $vars = "array(" . $out . ");";

            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                $results[] = eval("return $vars");
            }

        }
    } else {
        $results = "NO RESULTS";
    }
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();

    $this->results = array('num_rows' => $checker, $results);

    return $this->results;
}
```

EDIT FOR meagar

```
$bind = '$stmt->bind_param(\''. $sp . '\',' . $data . ');'; 
==
$bind = '$stmt->bind_param('ss', $input[0], $input[1]);); 
OR and so on
$bind = '$stmt->bind_param('sss', $input[0], $input[1], $input[2]););
```

EDIT FOR Incognito:

```
$input = array($_POST['pwnd']);

$data = readDB2($sql, $input, $output) {

public function readDB2($sql, $input, $output) {
    ...
    $inputn = count($input) - 1;
    for($i = 0; $i <= $inputn; $i++) {
            if($i !== $inputn) {
                $data .= '$input[' . $i . "],";
            } else {
                $data .= '$input[' . $i . "]";
            }
            $sp .= "s";
        }
        $bind = '$stmt->bind_param(\''. $sp . '\',' . $data . ');';
        eval("return $bind");

    ...
}
```

in my result

```
$bind = '$stmt->bind_param(\''. $sp . '\',' . $data . ');';
```

gets

```
eval("return $bind");
```

gets

```
$stmt->bind_param('s', $input[0]);
```

not what you said.

Comment: Yes.  Yes you are vulnerable.  There is no need for the eval either.  You can use call_user_func_array...

Comment: can you give me a example how this could be exploited?

Comment: Can you use call_user_func_array instead?

Comment: i can try, but i used now eval, and wanted look if its exploit able, if yes how, so that i understand it :-) just saying its evil, dont helps me cause, i dont know why its bad and how it can exploited.

Comment: how is `readDB2` called?

Comment: $data = readDB2($sql, $input, $output);
var_dump($data);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fyi,  [call_user_func_array](http://www.php.net/call_user_func_array)() is how you call functions with unknown number of arguments.

```
array_unshift($input, str_repeat('s', count($input)));
$callable = array($stmt, 'bind_param');
call_user_func_array($callable, $input);
```

[array_unshift](http://www.php.net/array_unshift)() pushes the 'sss' string element to the front of the array(we want the front because it needs to be the first argument fed to bind_param)

$callable is the [callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback) psuedo type

also, in the future, if you find yourself using eval, familiarize yourself with php's [var_export](http://www.php.net/var_export)() function which can assist you with constructing safe strings. Try not to use eval though.

Answer (score 4):

You're evaluating user-submitted data, effectively allowing attackers to execute arbitrary code. This is the absolute worst security hole your application can have, bar none. I mean that. Your programs has literally the worse vulnerability a program can have.

You're passing in `$_POST['a']` as the `$input` parameter. The `$input` parameter gets treated like an array, and it's individual elements get appended to a string which is evaluated. If somebody posts executable code to your application, you could inadvertently run it.

I won't go so far as to actually post a working exploit, but suppose `$_POST['a']` contained a single element, which had the string `'); rmdir("/etc"); //`.

This line:

```
    $bind = '$stmt->bind_param(\''. $sp . '\',' . $data . ');';
```

turns into something like this:

```
    $stmt->bind_param(''); rmdir("/etc"); //);';
```

That is, the intent of your original statement is nullified, and instead the user has caused you to remove your `/etc` directory. Again, this is probably *not* a working example, but this is the sort of attack you're opening yourself up to by trusting user-submitted data enough to pass it to `eval`.

Comment: $data will actually contain only `$input[0]` (literally, not it's content!)

Comment: if you can see in my code, $sp and $data is my code, so it could be only, after my thinking always only:

see my edit: EDIT FOR meagar

only the variables could contain $bad user input, this bad input gets passed to mysqli->prepared statements, which should be not exploit able.

Comment: The first code part does not interpolate the incoming values. It just uses a raw `\$input[123]` in the evaled code. Not so sure about the second half and `$out`, but that might not be input (looks like a cumbersome varvars workaround, all quite silly hard to follow).

Comment: mario the 2nd - 3rd eval, is only my code no user interaction, only to create empty vars, how much are needed.

Comment: @user1015314: That's what I wonder about. If you know how arrays work, why do bind output variables? Why don't you use the results that `=fetch()` returns?

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand you. The output, is dynamic, so if i need 3 vars, it creates 3 vars, if 5 it creates 5 vars ... i tried this before with arrays, but mysqli wants vars not arrays (got a error that it wants vars).