# Update multiple rows with one query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How can I update hundreds of rows at once?

Like:
`UPDATE table SET a = ? WHERE b = ? AND c = 1`

but for many rows. The `?` parameters are arrays...

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528181/update-multiple-rows-with-one-query) but it uses CASE and I don't think I can do that...

---

Right now I have something like this:

```
foreach($values as $key => $value)
  $res = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE table SET a = ? WHERE b = ? AND c = 1');
  $res->execute(array($value, $key));
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you able to use CASE?

Comment: because the query would be huge...

Comment: a practical example with the array contents would help.

Comment: Does every element defined in `b` have an associated element in `a`? In other words, are you try to set the `a` column of each record to a different value?

Comment: huge may not mean wrong, or else just loop

Comment: djacobson, exactly (not the same value, each record will have a different value, associated with the value of b). I'm doing this in a foreach loop right now, but I was thinking there's a shorter way to do thing with just mysql

Comment: tip: You should `prepare()` outside of the loop.

Comment: try this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626510/create-dynamic-number-of-variables

Comment: What problem are you attempting to solve?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do it in a single run of a query, you'd need to use a `CASE` and [assemble the parameters programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/327274/90527). SQL doesn't support variadic prepared statements, and only [simple values](http://blog.oudamou.co.cc/2011/07/parallels-between-prepared-statements.html) can be parameterized.

Alternatively, define a statement to only take data for one row at a time and run the query in a loop. Repeated execution is how prepared statements are designed to be used for cases like this.

```
try {
    $query = $db->prepare('UPDATE table SET a = ? WHERE b = ? AND c = 1');
    foreach ($as as $i => $a) {
        $query->execute(array($a, $bs[$i]));
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: can you create a case statement and still take advantage of prepared statements for SQL Injection or would you have to escape each input "as the old days"

Comment: @JM4: it depends on what you need to parameterize. Prepared statements are analogous to functions, but only values (and not, e.g., column names) can be parameterized. As long as that's all you need, then a prepared statement will work fine. However, I recommend a solution analogous to my sample code, as it's simpler overall. Unlike functions, arguments to prepared statements can't be re-used, generally speaking, so instead you'll have to have separate parameters and repeat the values, which is error-prone.

Answer (score 4):

Use the CASE method as described in the link you provided, but build the query dynamically with the values you want.

Likely, this will be built with a for loop similar to how you're already doing it, but you will end up with a single query rather than querying your database every iteration.

Comment: the only downside to this (and it is a recommendation I myself make) is that you are unable to escape the inputted data with prepared statements like you otherwise would in single row statements.

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to insert your key value pairs (all at once) into a temporary table then do something like this:

```
UPDATE table t
SET t.a = (SELECT p.a FROM tmp p WHERE p.b = t.b)
WHERE t.b IN (SELECT p.b FROM tmp p) AND t.c = 1
```